# Array elements gets memory override leading to access violation exception

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke

From the beginning, sorry for the weird title, but i really don't know how to describe this problem in short phrase.

I'm trying to wrapp a c++ DLL using pinvoke method. I have this function:

```
C++ header:
int32_t __cdecl ShowAllCharacters(Uint32Array *Image);

C#:
[DllImport(@"x86\OCR.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ShowAllCharacters(ref IntPtr image);
```

Where IntPtr image leads to following struct:

```
C++ header:
typedef struct {
    int32_t dimSizes[2];
    uint32_t elt[1];
} Uint32ArrayBase;
typedef Uint32ArrayBase **Uint32Array;

C#:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct Uint32Array
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int[] dimSizes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    public uint[] elt;
}
```

Basically function return Uint32Array struct, which represents array of uint elements. In Uint32Array, dimSizes is array length (dimSizes elements need to be multiplied to receive size) and elt is the first element of the array. That means, this uint array can have dynamic length.

Now my usage:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr Destination, IntPtr Source, uint Length);

unsafe public static void ShowAllCharacters()
{
    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    OCRPinvoke.ShowAllCharacters(ref ptr);

    IntPtr imgPP = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(IntPtr));
    Uint32Array img = (Uint32Array)Marshal.PtrToStructure(imgPP, typeof(Uint32Array));

    uint[] dest = new uint[img.dimSizes[1] * img.dimSizes[0]];

    fixed (uint* arrPtr = img.elt)
    {
        fixed (uint* destPtr = dest)
        {
            CopyMemory((IntPtr)destPtr, (IntPtr)arrPtr, (uint)dest.Length * sizeof(uint)); // Access violation reading location 
        }
    }
}
```

My assumption is that this error is due to memory override before i'm able to copy uint array to managed array. Why? I know by fact that in some conditions, size of 'elt' array should be 5038848. If i'm setting SizeConst of the elt variable to 5038848, CopyMemory pass without exception

```
internal struct Uint32Array
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int[] dimSizes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5038848)]
    public uint[] elt;
}
```

I have also try to copy array by iterating through loop. Every time, accessing elt elements by index crashes on different index.

My question is if there is any way to lock some range of memory until i copy my array and then release it to being override by other processes?

Comment: Marshal.PtrToStructure() just isn't helpful here.  As long as you use CopyMemory(), just use (IntPtr)((long)dataIn + 8) to copy from.

Comment: You didn't show the C++ definition of `Uint32Array`. Also the manual marshaling seems excessively complete. Why did you opt for IntPtr?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this problem, inspired by @David Heffernan. He ask why marshaling manually?

Knowing that Uint32Array is sequential, we can read every value directly from pointers and then use Marshal.Copy to receive final managed array:

```
IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
OCRPinvoke.ShowAllCharacters(ref ptr);
imagePtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr);

int height = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
int width = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr + sizeof(int));

int[] img = new int[width * height];
Marshal.Copy(ptr + sizeof(int) * 2, img, 0, img.Length);
```